# Postgresql information_schema.sequences shows wrong start_value

Tags: postgresql, sequence, information-schema

Can anyone explain this to me:

This is my sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE core.seqsynceodlogw   
  INCREMENT 10  
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 492604
  CACHE 1; 

ALTER TABLE core.seqsynceodlogw    OWNER TO acenter;
```

You can see that start value is 492604.

This is the information_schema query:

```
select * 
from information_schema.sequences 
where increment = '10' 
and sequence_schema = 'core' 
and sequence_name = 'seqsynceodlogw'
```

In the query result set says that start_value is 490691.

Does anyone know what value is this start_value in information_schema or why is different from one in the sequence?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5ddd4/1 Maybe you did create the sequence differently

Comment: Sequence was created with create script like this one above, but later on was restarted with 4. (alter sequence core.seqsynceodlogw restart with 4;).

Comment: Maybe information schema did not collect that change.

Comment: Is there a way to "refresh" information_shema?

Comment: Vacuum might refresh things. Some values in the system catalogs are maintained lazily. They're guaranteed to be right under certain circumstances, but not under others. I don't remember which values or what circumstances.  (Sequences are not currently documented to be maintained lazily, though.)

Comment: Unfortunately, vacuum did not solve this problem.
I tried vacuum full verbose.

Comment: This shouldn't happen.  There are no lazy updates and there is no need to vacuum.  The start value is stored when the sequence is created and that's it.  My only explanation would be a bug or corruption.

Answer (score 1):

the code provided by yoy contains cache 1, its not possible to put it one.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "SYSTEM"."SEQSYNCEODLOGW"  
  MINVALUE 1 
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 
  INCREMENT BY 10 
  START WITH 492604 
  CACHE 2 NOORDER  NOCYCLE
```

if you check the nextval as:

```
select SEQSYNCEODLOGW.nextval from dual;
```

then you can check the value 492604

Comment: I think you are confusing Postgres and Oracle. There is no `dual` in Postgres and there is no `sequence_name.nextval` in Postgres. And besides: you should never, ever create user objects in the `SYSTEM` schema in Oracle.